# C++ WinApi Fillrect() crashes (multiple rects)

Tags: c++, winapi, crash

i am trying to get used to WinApi and decided to make a GUI for a sudoku-generator i programmed.
It should adjust dynamicly to the windowsize the user chooses.
So far everything works as inteded, but if the WM_PAINT-msg is sent too often in a short window of time (eg changing the size of the window) the program crashes.

```
    LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    stringstream ss; //not used
    RECT rect;
    int w;
    int h;
    HBRUSH coluns=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(50,120,180));
    HBRUSH colsel=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(80,150,220));
    HBRUSH colmso=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(50,70,190));
    switch (message)
        {
        case WM_SIZE:            //
            {
                GetWindowRect(hwnd,&rect);
                menu.wndw=rect.right-rect.left;        //menu is a class to store important information
                menu.wndh=rect.bottom-rect.top;
                h=menu.wndh;
                w=menu.wndw;
                for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
                {
                    for(int j=1;j<10;j++)
                    {
                        menu.feld[i][j].SetSpace((w/4)+((i-1)*(w/20))+i+(2*((i-1)/3)),(h/4)+((j-1)*(h/20))+j+(2*((j-1)/3)),(w/4)+((i)*(w/20))+i+(2*((i-1)/3)),(h/4)+((j)*(h/20))+j+(2*((j-1)/3)));
                    }     
                }           //feld is a class wich exists in a 10x10 array with the 0s not being used
                InvalidateRect(hwnd,NULL, TRUE);
            }
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            {
                RECT re;
                w=menu.wndw;
                h=menu.wndh;
                hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd,&ps);
                re.left=(w/4)-4;
                re.top=(h/4)-4;
                re.right=(w/4)+9*(w/20)+18;
                re.bottom=(h/4)+9*(h/20)+18;
                FillRect(hdc,&re,CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0)));
                for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
                {
                    for(int j=1;j<10;j++)
                    {
                        re=menu.feld[i][j].GetSpace();
                        if(menu.feld[i][j].GetSelect()==uns)
                            if(FillRect(hdc,&re,coluns)==0)
                                MessageBox(hwnd, "fail","fail",0);
                        if(menu.feld[i][j].GetSelect()==mso)
                            if(FillRect(hdc,&re,colmso)==0)
                                MessageBox(hwnd, "fail","fail",0);
                        if(menu.feld[i][j].GetSelect()==sel)
                            if(FillRect(hdc,&re,colsel)==0)
                                MessageBox(hwnd, "fail","fail",0);

                    }
                }
                EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            }
            break;
```

http://www.pic-upload.de/view-22113118/Unbenannt.png.html 
here is a picture of what the executed program looks like.

Now as described earlier the program will crash if u change the windowsize in a lot of small steps. After calling the MW_PAINT msg for ~10 times the window will just freeze with 1 of the rects being white instead of the desired color (random one, different every time).
my assumption is that i need to release some kind of resources because mby a stack will overflow or smth, but i have really no idea where i could have a leak in my program.

i would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 4):

You create three brush handles every single time your window procedure executes. These handles are never tidied up. And then inside the `WM_PAINT` handler, you create a brush which you pass to `FillRect` and so can never destroy it.

So you leak three handles every time the window procedure executes (which happens a lot), and one more every time it handles `WM_PAINT`. Simply put, your program leaks like a sieve!

You should consider creating these brushes when the window is created, and destroying them when the window is destroyed. Or perhaps creating them inside the `WM_PAINT` handler, and destroying them as soon as you have finished using them. But since they have constant colors it is probably best to create 4 brushes up front, once and for all.

Answer (score 1):

You are leaking `GDI` resources as member *David Heffernan* said.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the example of how to properly use brushes in your application-pay attention to `WM_COMMAND` handler in that example.

If you **do not use stock GDI objects** you must delete them after you are done working with them.

Here is the simple example that fills window with red brush in `WM_PAINT` handler:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPain( hdc, &ps );
        HBRUSH hbrRedBrush = CreateSolidBrush( RGB( 255, 0, 0 ) );
        RECT r;
        GetClientRect( hWnd, &r );
        FillRect( hdc, &r, hbrRedBrush );
        DeleteObject( hbrRedBrush ); //you must delete GDI object!
        EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );
    }
    return 0L;
```

In your case, I would make 4 `static` brushes and rework my code a little, adding the proper cleanup in `WM_CLOSE` handler. Below are the suggested changes:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, 
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // add static before HBRUSH
    static HBRUSH coluns=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(50,120,180));
    static HBRUSH colsel=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(80,150,220));
    static HBRUSH colmso=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(50,70,190));
    static HBRUSH BlackBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));

    switch (message)
    {
    // this is the problematic handler
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            //the changed part
            FillRect( hdc, &re, BlackBrush );

        }
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            DeleteObject( BlackBrush );
            DeleteObject( coluns );
            DeleteObject( colsel );
            DeleteObject( colmso );
            // other clean up code
        }
        break;
```

### IMPORTANT NOTE:

This time you used `FillRect` API, but next time you might load bitmaps and other stuff that **require** from you to **restore `HDC` into original state** after you are done with drawing.

You do that like this:

```
HBITMAP bmpOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject( hdc, myBitmap );
// bmpOld stores the original state of the device context
// you do something with myBitmap
// then you return device context into original state 
// by selecting the original value, bmpOld, back into device context 
SelectObject( hdc, oldBmp ); 
DeleteObject( myBitmap );
```

Again, pay attention to `WM_COMMAND` handler in the above `MSDN` example to see how they did it.

[Here](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/) is the link to a great `Win32` API tutorial for beginners-give it a go.

In the end I recommend you [this tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html) for detecting `GDI` leaks.

If you have further questions leave a comment and I will reply as soon as possible.

Best regards and good luck!